# short sql challenge with multiple next row on a resultset with group by and having count

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m coding a wiki and want to show the changes on a users inputs from other users.

Let’s say a table called Input is used as an input log, simplified to table (columns):

Input (in_id, to_id, text, us_id)

in_id is the primary key of the table Input

to_id is the primary key of the table Topic

text is some text

us_id is the primary key of the table User

The following example…

```
+ - - - - - + - - - - -+ - - - - -+ - - - - -+
|  in_id    |  to_id   |  text    |  us_id   |      
+ - - - - - + - - - - -+ - - - - -+ - - - - -+
|     1     |    12    |   foo    |     1    |  
|     3     |    13    |   bar    |     1    |      
|     4     |    34    |   blub   |     5    |      
|     5     |    12    |   fo     |     5    |      
|     6     |    12    |   f      |     1    |      
|     7     |    13    |   b      |     6    |      
|     8     |    13    |   ba     |     1    |      
|     9     |    13    |   bar    |     7    |      
+ - - - - - + - - - - -+ - - - - -+ - - - - -+
```

… should lead to the following result for the user with us_id = 1

```
+ - - - - - + - - - - -+ - - - - -+ - - - - -+
|  in_id    |  to_id   |  text    |  us_id   |      
+ - - - - - + - - - - -+ - - - - -+ - - - - -+
|     5     |    12    |   fo     |     5    |      
|     7     |    13    |   b      |     6    |
|     9     |    13    |   bar    |     7    |      
+ - - - - - + - - - - -+ - - - - -+ - - - - -+
```

My query idea:

I`m looking for every next row in the (resultset, that shows all to_id’s with multiple  to_id's  with at least one  us_id = 1,) where us_id != 1

Various sql statements didn’t work, because I didn’t manage to handle the next row of the resultset.

SQL Statements for a single next row...

```
SELECT MIN(in_id) FROM Input WHERE in_id > (in_id out of the resultset)
```

...and selection of to_id’s that exist more than once...

```
GROUP BY in_id HAVING COUNT(in_id)>1
```

...are not the problem.

How should it be done?

Comment: For me looks like you need something like oracle "connect by level" or so, but I'm not very good in MySQL so can't give more info.

Comment: OK - thx - that got me to the topic 'recursive queries' in mysql

Comment: The question is not clear. (1) Do we want to check **only** topics that were initially written by us_id **1**? (2) assuming to_id **123** was edited by the following users, one after the other: **1**,**2**,**3**,**1**,**4**, Do we want to retrieve user **3** or not since he was actually editing us_id **2** and not **1**. Do we want to retrieve us_id **2** as all? Because us_id **1** re-edited the code  since then, which makes us_id **4** the last one to edit us_id **1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the in_id sequence is incementing and "next row" means in_id is higher then "previous row", the following query yields the result:

```
select input.*
from 
    (select min(in_id) as idmin, to_id  
            from input 
            where us_id=1 group by to_id
    ) mintable, 
    input 
where 
   (input.to_id = mintable.to_id and input.in_id > mintable.idmin) 
   and us_id <> 1;
```

The inner table will select the pages where the user started editing, the second query will select all subsequent changes to this page.

Comment: I just tested your solution positiv! Simple and clear query. Thanks a lot. Creating the mintable inside the FROM was a big learning for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to utilise some queries like this

```
select in_id, 
to_id, 
text, 
us_id 
from Input 
where to_id IN 
(select to_id from input where us_id = 1 group by us_I'd)
```